# How do I get the total population of each specific year from a table in SQLServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Have one Table Population

```
Stateid  StateName  Year  Popution

01      xx          2008     200000

02      xy          2008     400000

01      xx          2009     500000

02      xy          2009     900000
```

So need Result each state Total popution in 2009?

```
Expected Result xx:700000,xy:1300000
```

how to get this result. any one please suggestion me?

Comment: why do you re ask the same question? the first was put on hold you should respond on that not repost

Comment: Population figures are generally _already_ additive - it's a total _as of that year_ so adding up prior years would make no sense, unless you were adding births and deaths.

Comment: @Liath: The other question was put on hold for not providing enough information. Now he's providing more information on the expected result, so it is *not* a duplicate.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, shouldn't the OP edit his/her original question instead of posting a new similar one ?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar everyone can edit their own posts. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, sure , its the same user, and OP can always edit his/her own post

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will give you what you say you want.

```
select statename, sum(population) thesum
from population
maybe a where clause
group by statename
```

However, what you say you want is very strange.  For state xx, the 50000 people in 2009 probably include many of the people who lived there in 2008.  The question, as you describe it, means you count those people twice.

Comment: Maybe the numbers contain a population *increase* between the years? Then it would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up all the population values for the same state over all the years up to the given year, you could try this:

```
DECLARE @year NVARCHAR(4)
SET @year = '2009'

SELECT Stateid, StateName, SUM(Popution) FROM
(
    SELECT Stateid, StateName, Popution FROM Population WHERE Year <= @year
) tmp
GROUP BY Stateid, Statename
```

This would in the inner query select all the records that have a year before or including the desired year. Then, then the sum is built per state.

Actually, you will only see this if your data is as follows:

```
Stateid  StateName  Year  Popution

01      xx          2008     200000

02      xy          2008     400000

01      xx          2009     500000

02      xy          2009     900000

01      xx          2010     600000

02      xy          2010     1000000
```

Then, if you evaluate until 2009, you'd get the numbers you expect.

```
01      xx          700000
02      xy          1300000
```

For 2010 you'd get

```
01      xx          1300000
02      xy          2300000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT
  [StateName], sum([Popution])
FROM Populations
GROUP BY [StateName]
ORDER BY [StateName];
```

Which gives

```
STATENAME   COLUMN_1
xx  700000
xy  1300000
```

[See here for a live fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/555f1/4).

Answer (score -2):

Your question is wrong you will not get the result of xx:700000 and xy=1300000 for the year 2009. But if you have more than one value in 2009. Then use the below query.

CREATE table test
(stateid INT,statename VARCHAR(500),yeard int,POPULATION INT)

select * FROM test

SELECT statename,SUM(POPULATION)
FROM test
WHERE yeard= 2009
GROUP BY statename

Regards
Moosa

Comment: Your answer is wrong. You expect that he wants the numbers for the year 2009. What is wants is the sum of all the values for the same state for all the years up to and including 2009.